# How to make columns in Bootstrap grid (instead of stacked)?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, css-grid, jsfiddle

I'm experimenting with [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) and using jsfiddle.net to create some quick and dirty tests.

I'm running into a brick wall on a really simple test however. I just want to see the grid system in Bootstrap, so I've duplicated their first example:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span4">Span 4</div>
  <div class="span8">Span 8</div>
</div>
```

However, it doesn't seem to work-- the "Span 4" and "Span 8" appear stacked rather than in the expected two-column layout.

Am I missing something obvious? Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8Xf2j/1/

Thanks

Comment: Try making the result frame (or the whole window) wider. Bootstrap is probably stacking the columns because the window is too small.

Comment: @grc -- d'oh! That was it. So simple-- I figured with those tiny text strings it couldn't be stacking, but I guess the viewport was still smaller than bootstrap required. Thanks!

Comment: Bootstrap probably works using media queries, so if the viewport is smaller than a set width it will stack the columns regardless of how wide they are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the `bootstrap-combined.min.css` file, it means that the [Responsive Layout](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive) is active.

Moreover, you have to use a `.container` to set the minimum width (if not, the body will fit the window, which will result in stacking anyway - on small screens).

Here is one way to use the grid : [Demo (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/8Xf2j/4/)

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="span4">Span 4</div>
      <div class="span8">Span 8</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You should notice that only the `bootstrap.min.css` file is included in the resources.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the width of **span** is already defined. Its total width is 960px(span4(320px) + span8(640px)  = span12(960px)). So jsfiddle is showing the result like this. Create an html file and try it, setting the border for your reference.